# Top Row Menu CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to website development/design so I've been struggling with getting a top row menu to work on my site. Here's the code I have so far. Any suggestions for things that might fit with my theme? I'm going for a dark green/blurry style, I've gotten one of the boxes to work however when I try to insert something to act as a background for a centered nav-bar, it doesn't even show up.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Montserrat+Alternates:wght@500&display=swap');
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    
}

section
{
    position: relative;
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: url(https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/692954070180298767/807238617075679252/unknown.png);
    background-attachment: fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

section .box
{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 700px;
    padding: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #000;
}

section .box:before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    right:  -20px;
    bottom: -20px;
    background: url(https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/692954070180298767/807238617075679252/unknown.png);
    backround-attachement: fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    filter: blur(10px)
}

section .box h2
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 48px;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

section .box p
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

section .box 
{
    width: 50rem;
    height: 10rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <section>
            
            <div class="box">
                <center>
                <h2 style="color:#ffffff";>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p style="color:#ffffff";>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                </center>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to web development! Have fun and keep learning.

A note in the beginning, try to use smaller images/background-images for the web (loading times for example).
For a navigation in your current layout, i would suggest something like this:

I removed ur inline html styling, it's unnecessary if you are using a stylesheet file. I also removed the `<center>` html tag, it's [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

Next steps i added/changed the color of all box elements `.box *` to `position: relative;` (for showing "above" your `:before` element) and set the color to white and centered it.
Then i added a navigation (in your html a new box element with a list in it). Set the list items to `display: inline-block` for a very simple navigation alignment.

```css
 
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Montserrat+Alternates:wght@500&display=swap');
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
 body
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        
    }

    section
    {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background: url(https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/692954070180298767/807238617075679252/unknown.png);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        display: grid;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    section .box
    {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 700px;
        padding: 50px;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,1);
        overflow: hidden;
        color: #000;
    }

    section .box:before
    {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -20px;
        left: -20px;
        right:  -20px;
        bottom: -20px;
        background: url(https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/692954070180298767/807238617075679252/unknown.png);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        display: grid;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100vh;
        filter: blur(10px);
    }

    section .box h2
    {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 0 20px;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 48px;
        z-index: 2;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    }

    section .box p
    {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 18px;
        z-index: 2;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    }

    section .box 
    {
        width: 50rem;
        height: 10rem;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
     section .box.navigation
    {
        width: 50rem;
        height: 5rem;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    
     section .box * {
       color: #ffffff;
       position: relative;
       text-align: center;
     }
     
     section .box.navigation ul li {
       list-style-type: none;
       display: inline-block;
     }

     section .box.navigation ul li a {
        display: block;
        margin: 10px;
     }
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="box navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</section>
```